# how to use the image in the <img> on Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, html

I have a local image in my folder. but I can't use this image. Folders structure:

[image]

I want to use logo.jpg in login.component.html. I am using this code:

```
<img src="img/logo.jpg">
```

But isn't work for me

Comment: the path of the image should be '**../../../img/logo.png**'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Supposing you are using @angular/cli try to move your `img` folder under `src\assets` and then do `<img src="assets/img/logo.jpg">`.

Standard way is to put assets to `assets` folder under your app source root. The builder is told in `angular.json` to include assets by defining  (for example):

`projects.<your-project>.architect.build.options.assets: [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ]`

Whatever is defined there will be copied verbatim to your `dist` folder.

Note that assets must be under src root, somewhere. Therefore trying to add `"src/../img"` to config will fail. At least with my config and CLI.

Edit: Just noticed you mention Angular5. That is long time ago but IIRC the config file there was named `.angular.json` (see the dot). The structure of config is slightly different, just look for "assets".

Answer (score 0):

you need to provider the entire relative path

i think it's:

```
src="../.././img/logo.jpg"
```

or maybe

```
 src="../../../img/logo.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

change the path to:  `'../../../img/logo.png'`

or Move the imgs to under assets in src, src/assets

and then refer in your img src as:

`img src="assets/img/logo.png">`